# Selectively load JSON data into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have some json data that I want to put into a pandas dataframe. The json looks like this:

```
{'date': [20170629,
  20170630,
  20170703,
  20170705,
  20170706,
  20170707],
 'errorMessage': None,
 'seriesarr': [{'chartOnlyFlag': 'false',
   'dqMaxValidStr': None,
   'expression': 'DB(FXO,V1,EUR,USD,7D,VOL)',
   'freq': None,
   'frequency': None,
   'iDailyDates': None,
   'label': '',
   'message': None,
   'plotPoints': [0.0481411225888,
    0.0462401214563,
    0.0587196848727,
    0.0765737640932,
    0.0678912611279,
    0.0675766942022],
   }
```

I am trying to create a pandas DataFrame with `'date'` as the index and `'plotPoints'` as a second column. I don't need any of the other infomation.

I've tried

`df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, record_path = 'date', meta = ['seriesarr', ['plotPoints']])`

When I do this I get the following error:

```
KeyError: ("Try running with errors='ignore' as key %s is not always present", KeyError('plotPoints',)
```

Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `seriesarr` an array of size 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, `json_normalize` may not be able to help you here. It might instead just be easier to extract that data and then load it into a dataframe directly. If need be, convert to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
date = data.get('date')
plotPoints = data.get('seriesarr')[0].get('plotPoints')

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y%m%d'),
                   'plotPoints' : plotPoints})
df
        date  plotPoints
0 2017-06-29    0.048141
1 2017-06-30    0.046240
2 2017-07-03    0.058720
3 2017-07-05    0.076574
4 2017-07-06    0.067891
5 2017-07-07    0.067577
```

<sub>This is under the assumption that your data is exactly as shown in the question.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I clearly need to learn more about json.

Answer (score 1):

As @COLDSPEED pointed out, getting data directly from dictionary columns will be suitable since 'plotPoints' is contained within a list of dict.

A list comprehension variation is as below that has date as index and plotpoints as column..

```
col1 = data['date']
adict = dict((k,v)  for d in data['seriesarr'] for k,v in d.iteritems() )
col2 = adict['plotPoints']
pd.DataFrame(data= col2, index=col1)

>>>              0
20170629  0.048141
20170630  0.046240
20170703  0.058720
20170705  0.076574
20170706  0.067891
20170707  0.067577
```